# DateRagePicker Automatically opens the date range selection filter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, daterangepicker

```
 modal.find('.start_date').daterangepicker({

timePicker: true,
callback: function (startDate, endDate, period) {
$(this).val(startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' – ' + endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
},
locale: {
format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
},
ranges: {
'Today': [moment(), moment()],
'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
}
});
```

above is my javascript code

as you can see in picture filter automatically pop up when open the model

[automatically pop up filter (see photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7JM0.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: sorry for late reply. i just found the thing which was causing this problem